# try/catch is not catching exception

Tags: flutter, error-handling, try-catch

I'm using the `google_sign_in` package and I'm a bit new to error handling. I surrounded two lines in a try/catch statement and I get the exception in VSCode even though I check for PlatformExceptions. The line that gives me the error is where I set the `googleSignInAccount` variable. I tried using `Future#catchError` but no luck their either. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```dart
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount;
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication;
    try {
      googleSignInAccount = await userRepository.googleSignIn.signIn();
      googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'sign_in_canceled') {
        print('sign in canceled');
        return Future.error(e);
      }
      rethrow;
    } on Exception {
      print('an exception has occured');
    }
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );
```

Comment: Your exception might be handled, however your Visual Studio Code is showing your the exception anyways. This is the case if you have `All Exceptions` enabled in your debug settings. In that case I'd recommend to disable that option and enable `Uncaught Exceptions`. Let me know if that's the problem.

Comment: Nope, only "Uncaught Exceptions" is enabled.